# GluonCV - Export object detection models to Android

Tags: python, android, object-detection, mxnet

I’ve been using GluonCV for object detection, and I was trying to figure out how to export these models to Android (I re-trained a few models on my own dataset, so I’d like to export those).

I’m really new to the topic, so I was looking for a place to start. Should I use an external tool (like BeeWare or Kivy), or can I do everything by native mxnet/GluonCV tools?
I found [this discussion](https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/how-can-i-export-ssd512-to-android-phone/3080), but as you can see the first link in the answer is not working anymore, and instructions in the [amalgamation repository](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/amalgamation) are not particularly clear.

I tried to clone the repo and run "make" from the amalgamation subfolder, but I’m repeatedly getting this error:

```
Makefile:80: recipe for target 'nnvm.d' failed
make[3]: *** [nnvm.d] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/lews/PycharmProjects/incubator-mxnet/amalgamation'
cp: cannot stat 'nnvm.d': No such file or directory
cat: nnvm.cc: No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'temp' to '../../../../amalgamation/nnvm.cc': No such file or directory
```

Any indication would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Android is moving toward its [NN API](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/neuralnetworks) so what I would recommend is to try the following workflow (1) convert [`gluoncv` to ONNX](https://mxnet.apache.org/api/python/docs/tutorials/deploy/export/onnx.html) then [convert ONNX to NN API](https://github.com/JDAI-CV/DNNLibrary)